# React not rendering list of Divs

Tags: reactjs, list, render

I am a little new to React and know this is a lame doubt , but i am hooked to this question

```
class App extends React.Component {

  count = 0;
  arr = [];

  
  
  fillArr = () => {
    for(let i = this.count; i < this.count + 5; ++i){
      this.arr.push(i);
    }
    this.arr = this.arr.map((val) => {
      return <div>{val}</div>
    })
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fillArr();
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <div>{this.arr}</div>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

I don't know why it is not rendering the list of item as i want like
PS: please ignore silly errors

Answer (score 0):

React does not render anything unless you use `state` to store values to be viewed and use `setState` method to change the viewing values in class components. But still you can save thing in `this.<any_property>` which does not affect rendering. In your case `this.count`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  count = 0;

  state = {
    arr: []
  };

  fillArr = () => {
    this.setState({
      arr: Array.from(Array(5).keys()).map((val) => {
        return <div>{val}</div>;
      })
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fillArr();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.arr}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```